# How to remove undefined while show json data

Tags: jquery

I am iterating customer List in jquery user each as follow

```
 $.post("customer", {param: cid, order: order}, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
               $.each(data.customerList, function (i, obj) {
                        $("#" + tid).append('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + obj.customerName + '</td><td>' + obj.address + '</td>'
                                + '<td>' + obj.city + '</td><td>' + obj.state + '</td><td>' + obj.country + '</td><td>' + obj.mobno + '</td></tr>');
                    });
```

This code is working properly and fetching data properly .
My problem is it is showing undefined for null fields.
how to resolve this problem.

Comment: To check is a variable is null: if (var == null) { ... } but Jaqen H'ghar response is more elegant.

Comment: you can use `ternary operator` like `obj.state  != null ? obj.state : ""` meaning if `obj.state` is not equal to null show the `obj.state` else ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|| ""`:

```
$.post("customer", {param: cid, order: order}, function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $.each(data.customerList, function (i, obj) {
      $("#" + tid).append('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + (obj.customerName || "") + '</td><td>' + (obj.address || "") + '</td>'
      + '<td>' + (obj.city || "") + '</td><td>' + (obj.state || "") + '</td><td>' + (obj.country || "") + '</td><td>' + (obj.mobno || "") + '</td></tr>');
   });
```

If the field is empty it will set an empty value instead of `undefined`

See following example:

```js
var test = {
   prop1: "Test value",
   prop2: null,
   prop3: undefined
};

console.log(test.prop1 || "empty");
console.log(test.prop2 || "empty");
console.log(test.prop3 || "empty");
console.log(test.prop4 || "empty");
```

Comment: It also removing table border between 2 cells

Comment: @xrcwrn It might be because your table cell is empty now. In your case try to use another default value like `|| "&nbsp;"` for example so the cell will not be empty

Comment: || "empty" is also hiding the cell border

Comment: @xrcwrn you might need to wrap it in `( )`. Anyway take a look in this JSFiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/dzx7g1yL/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/dzx7g1yL/2/) I changed your code only little bit because I dont have your full version. It keeps the borders of the empty cells.